# Mongodb not working either addUser or createUser

Tags: mongodb

I am using old version of mongo version 2.2.3
I install it on 64 bit server

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 7F0CEB10

echo 'deb http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart dist 10gen' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb.list

sudo apt-get update

apt-get install mongodb-10gen=2.2.3
```

When I tried to create user

```
1.
     pt@ubuntu:~$ mongo
    MongoDB shell version v3.4.0
    connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
    MongoDB server version: 2.2.3
    WARNING: shell and server versions do not match
```

2.

```
 > use admin
switched to db admin
> db.addUser("admin","password")
2016-12-21T17:46:09.712+0530 E QUERY    [main] TypeError: db.addUser is not a function :
@(shell):1:1




    db.createUser({user:"admin",pwd:"password",roles:["adminUser"]})
        2016-12-21T17:48:02.435+0530 E QUERY    [main] Error: 'createUser' command not found.  This is most likely because you are talking to an old (pre v2.6) MongoDB server :
        DB.prototype.createUser@src/mongo/shell/db.js:1281:1
        @(shell):1:1
```

Not clearly mentioned in mongodocs.

Answer (score 2):

If you are not already aware from the messages on your console, you are mixing the shell and server versions. The shell versions may be backward compatible to a certain extent but server versions are not. So looks like your intention is to use 2.2.3 server.

https://docs.mongodb.com/v2.2/reference/method/db.addUser/

```
db.addUser("admin" , "pass" , true )
```

The createUser is a new command in 2.6 server version.

On a side note you should try using 3.4 server version.

More here for 2.2 version https://docs.mongodb.com/v2.2/tutorial/control-access-to-mongodb-with-authentication/#add-users